# How to refresh Child popup window from parent window?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am opening a child pop up window from parent window in asp.net using this server code which is on a linkbutton..

```
myScript = "<script>window.open('frmAdvanceClaimPopup.aspx','frmAdvanceClaimPopup','height=400px, width=1024px,status= no,resizable= no, scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no'); </script>";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", myScript, false);
```

But the problem with this is that I want the child window to get refreshed everytime I click the calling linkbutton on parent page. OR atleast close the child page first if its already open and then call it again. How can this be done?

**UPDATE**

Parent Page:
For eg: 
I have 
`linkbutton 100`
`linkbutton 101`
`linkbutton 102`

If I click 100 it shows pop up with 100 displayed on it (using session). 
If I close this child pop up and then click 101 on parent, then it will open child pop up with 101 on it which is correct. 
But If I do not close the child pop up with which atthe moment shows 101 but still click 102 on parent then it does not show 102 on child instead it still shows the old value 101 no matter what link i click.

Comment: You are calling it server side so it will be refresh when you click link button

Comment: It does not. For EG..
I have LINK BUTTON 100, LINK BUTTON 101 if I click 100 then it shows me 100 on child pop up but if i then click 101  without closing the child pop up it  still shows 100 in pop up

Comment: It will man if you have code it server side make sure its does not poping out behind your previous popup

Comment: Do you call this RegisterSratupScript everytime when the link button is clicked or not?

Comment: @Zane yes it is called everytime. But only one window gets popped up no matter how many times you click it. See my update to understand the issue .

Comment: If so then it must be refreshed as per the link button you click, http://jsfiddle.net/8jded/. Can you give the code how it shows the values 100, 102, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reference to the popup window, you can reload the window when you click the linkbutton through a click event or something similar.

```
var popup = window.open('frmAdvanceClaimPopup.aspx','frmAdvanceClaimPopup','height=400px, width=1024px,status= no,resizable= no, scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no')
```

You need to make sure that the variable is accessible otherwise this won't work.

```
$( "#linkButton" ).click(function() {
  popup.location.reload(); 
});
```

Comment: I do not have a reference as you can see in my code

Comment: I found a simpler way(which I derived from your answer).. 
`myScript = "<script>var popup = window.open('frmAdvanceClaimPopup.aspx','frmAdvanceClaimPopup','height=400px, width=1024px,status= no,resizable= no, scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no');popup.location.reload(); </script>";`